# Developing 3rd party plugins/addons for Flash Player

Tags: flash, plugins, add-on

I've seen something like 3rd party software that works along with the Flash Player and extends its functionality. For example: video decoding, opening external files, etc.

Does anyone know how such things can be built? Please provide any useful info and maybe links.

Answer (score 1):

[Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/) allows you to compile C code and call it from AS3 (Flash language). 3D engines, unziping, fast data processing, transcoding, emulating are some of the applications Alchemy has been designed for.

Comment: yea, I know it. but I'm talking about separate software that a user installs to a computer.

Comment: You could help us by showing us examples of what you want to build (the software you have seen).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't provide an example... A year or two ago, I've seen a live video stream. The first time a user entered the page with a flash video player, it was required to install a 3rd party software. After that the stream could be played with flash player.

Answer (score 0):

Such functionality EXISTS in flash player. You can not develop plugins for Flash player. you can develop applications which run on Flash Player. These will be developed in ActionScript (the language) using an IDE like Adobe's [Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder/features.html), [Flash Professional](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash.html) or the opensource [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page) to name a few

OR, if you want to develop Flash player, look [here](http://www.adobe.com/aboutadobe/careeropp/) :)

Comment: The software I saw was built with C++ or something like that. It was like additional software. Maybe launched as a separate plugin in a webpage, and Flash application communicated with it via javascript... can't say exactly, just guessing.

Comment: If you mean AIR applications which can be installed locally and are written in ActionScript, check out http://www.adobe.com/products/air.html

Answer (score 0):

You may create an AIR application and communicate with your web swf via [`LocalConnection`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html) which is said to work

> Between content (SWF-based or HTML-based) in an **AIR application** and **SWF content running in a browser**

You AIR application would do whatever you want it to do (open a local file...) and send the gathered data to a method is your web SWF. Example of usage provided on the [`LocalConnection`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html) page.

Comment: This tip could be helpful some day, thank you! But it's not about my question.

Comment: Then, I definitely don't get what you want... Sorry!